# File extraction errors

Tags: ssd, archiving, hard-drive, crc

I have a gigabyte 970 motherboard.  A 64 gb SSD, a 1tb HDD and an AMD fx6200 CPU.  Graphics AMD Radeon hd 6870.  8 gb ram. Nothing is overclocked, everything is stock.  So I downloaded a few large archives (saved to the hdd) and I extracted them with 7zip and I got a CRC error. I Tried using winrar and for the same issue.  I tested my ram with memtest and moved my hdds around, used new data caves, replaced the drive, reinstalled windows.  And it fails still. Sometimes I get a bsod error 101.  I changed ide and ahci setttings to try to fix.  I was able to extract them from a network drive fine, so the files are fine.  Windows runs fine, so there isn't a CPU problem.  I updated bios to f8e.  I do have indexing data stored on the HDD, but that shouldn't do anything. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Run a memtest from a Linux LiveCD to eliminate the RAM as a potential source of corruption. Also check SMART data from your HDD to see if it is failing.